# Display number of downloaded files on Inno Setup TDownloadWizardPage

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

Suppose that I'm using the example `CodeDownloadFiles.iss` and I would like to notice to the user the Status of Download writing the number of progress file download *"N of Y file"*.

I thought to retrieve the Total Number of selected Components but how can change the label *"Downloading additional files..."*? I tried the following command but it is not supported by the class:

```pascal
TDownloadWizardPage.DownloadingLabel := 'Downloading additional files... file 1 of 3, please wait...'
```

This is the function, as you can see I didn't write how to retrieve the Total Number of selected components; I'll appreciate getting a suggestion also for this task to retrieve it programmatically... maybe creating a New Function that checks any components? :

```pascal
function NextButtonClick(CurPageID: Integer): Boolean;
begin
  //Download Components
  if CurPageID = wpReady then begin
    DownloadPage.Clear;

    if WizardIsComponentSelected('Database\ABC') then begin
      TDownloadWizardPage.DownloadingLabel := 'Downloading additional files... file 1 of 3, please wait...'
      DownloadPage.Add('https://example.com/MyDB1.sqlite', 'MyDB1.sqlite', '');
    end;
    if WizardIsComponentSelected('Database\DEF') then begin
      TDownloadWizardPage.DownloadingLabel := 'Downloading additional files... file 2 of 3, please wait...'
      DownloadPage.Add('https://example.com/MyDB2.sqlite', 'MyDB2.sqlite', '');;
    end;
    if WizardIsComponentSelected('Database\GHI') then begin
      TDownloadWizardPage.DownloadingLabel := 'Downloading additional files... file 3 of 3, please wait...'
      DownloadPage.Add('https://example.com/MyDB3.sqlite', 'MyDB3.sqlite', '');;
    end;
    DownloadPage.Show;
    try
      try
        DownloadPage.Download;
        Result := True;
      except
        SuppressibleMsgBox(AddPeriod(GetExceptionMessage), mbCriticalError, MB_OK, IDOK);
        Result := False;
      end;
    finally
      DownloadPage.Hide;
    end;
  end else
  Result := True;
end;
```

How can I solve this problem? And how could I count the total number of selected components?

Thank you for any suggestions!

Answer (score 3):

- It's `DownloadPage.Msg1Label.Caption`, not `TDownloadWizardPage.DownloadingLabel`
- `DownloadPage.Add` does not download the file, so you cannot update the label on its call. It's `DownloadPage.Download` that *downloads* the files.

What you can do:

- Count the total number files to download by increasing a counter everytime you call `DownloadPage.Add`.

  Global variables:

  ```pascal
  var
    DownloadCount: Integer;
    DownloadFile: Integer;
    PreviousDownload: string;
  ```

  After

  ```pascal
  DownloadPage.Clear;
  ```

  add

  ```pascal
  DownloadCount := 0;
  DownloadFile := 0;
  PreviousDownload := '';
  ```

  At each `DownloadPage.Add` do:

  ```pascal
  DownloadPage.Add(...);
  Inc(DownloadCount);
  ```
- Use `TOnDownloadProgress` to monitor the download process. On each change of `Url`, update the label.

  Assuming your `InitializeWizard` (or other) creates the download page with `TOnDownloadProgress` handler like this:

  ```pascal
  procedure InitializeWizard;
  begin
    DownloadPage :=
      CreateDownloadPage(
        SetupMessage(msgWizardPreparing), SetupMessage(msgPreparingDesc),
        @OnDownloadProgress);
  end;
  ```

  update your `OnDownloadProgress` handler (or any other) to do:

  ```pascal
  function OnDownloadProgress(
    const Url, FileName: String; const Progress, ProgressMax: Int64): Boolean;
  begin
    if Url <> PreviousDownload then
    begin
      Inc(DownloadFile);
      PreviousDownload := Url;
      DownloadPage.Msg1Label.Caption :=
        Format('Downloading additional files... file %d of %d, please wait...', [
          DownloadFile, DownloadCount]);
    end;
    Result := True;
  end;
  ```

Comment: Amazing!! @Martin Prikryl, thank your post are always great!